# How to add properties of von Mises circular distribution data to my data

Tags: r, plot

When I generate von Mises circular distribution data...

```
dummy.data <- rvonmises(n=10, mu=circular(0), kappa=0)
```

...I can make radial plot (by `plot(dummy.data)`) because the `rvonmises` function generates not only the vales but also **data properties**:

```
str(dummy.data)
Classes 'circular', 'numeric'  atomic [1:10] 2.04 2.633 0.54 0.776 0.353 ...
  ..- attr(*, "circularp")=List of 6
  .. ..$ type    : chr "angles"
  .. ..$ units   : chr "radians"
  .. ..$ template: chr "none"
  .. ..$ modulo  : chr "asis"
  .. ..$ zero    : num 0
  .. ..$ rotation: chr "counter"
```

**How can I create (transfer?) these properties to my real life data stored in vector format?**

Because when I try to plot my data, I can get only ordinary xyplot.

```
radian.values <- seq(from = 0, to  = 2*pi, length = 250)
my.data <- sample(radian.values, 500, replace = TRUE)
plot(my.data) # ordinary xyplot.... :(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using a package, perhaps `circular`?

At any rate, in the `str` output we can see that the rvonmises function creates a class `circular`, which the plot function recognizes.

Look at `?circular` to find how to create such an object from existing data.